$I_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\tan x))^2}{1-\sin 2x}dx$ & $I_2=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln(1-\sin x))(\cot x)dx$ then$|\frac{I_1}{I_2}|=?$
If  $$I_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\tan x))^2}{1-\sin 2x}dx$$ and $$I_2=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln(1-\sin x))(\cot x)dx$$ then evaluate $$\left|\frac{I_1}{I_2}\right|$$
My Attempt
$$I_1=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{(\ln(\tan x))^2}{1-\sin 2x}dx=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{(\ln(\tan x))^2}{1-\sin 2x}dx$$
Taking $t=\tan x$, the integral transforms to
$$I_1=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{(\ln t)^2}{(1-t)^2}dt$$
Putting $t=1-\sin x$ in $I_2$ we have $$I_2=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln t}{1-t}dt$$
What to do after this

DOes it help if you intgegrate I_1 by parts?

The limits $0$ and $1$ are posing problems

Integrating by parts:
$$\int \frac{\log^2 t}{(1-t)^2} dt = \left[\frac{\log^2 t}{1-t} \right]-2\int \frac{\log t}{t(1-t)} dt  $$
$$ = \frac{\log^2 t}{1-t} -2\int \frac{\log t}{t} dt -2\int \frac{\log t}{1-t} dt  $$
$$ = \frac{\log^2 t}{1-t} -\log^2 t -2\int \frac{\log t}{1-t} dt  $$
$$ = \frac{t \log^2 t}{1-t}  -2\int \frac{\log t}{1-t} dt  $$
Therefore
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 t}{(1-t)^2} dt = \lim_{t \to 1-} \frac{t \log^2 t}{1-t}  -  \lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{t \log^2 t}{1-t} -2\int_0^1 \frac{\log t}{1-t} dt  \tag 1$$
For both of the limits, set $t=e^x$, then
$$\lim_{t \to 1-} \frac{t \log^2 t}{1-t}=\lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{x^2 e^x}{1-e^x}=\lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{x^2 }{e^{-x}-1}=\lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{2x}{-e^{-x}}=0$$
$$\lim_{t \to 0+} \frac{t \log^2 t}{1-t}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x^2 e^x}{1-e^x} =\lim_{x \to -\infty} x^2 e^x \lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{1}{1-e^x} $$
The second limit is $1$ and the first is
$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} x^2 e^x =\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{x^2}{e^{-x}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2x}{-e^{-x}}=\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac{2}{e^{-x}}=0$$
and so both limits in (1) are zero and so
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2 t}{(1-t)^2} dt =  -2\int_0^1 \frac{\log t}{1-t} dt  \tag 2$$

The limits can be easily evaluated by using standard limits, but still the answer deserves an upvote. +1

Using the series $(*)$ for  $|t|<1$,
$$
\frac{1}{1-t}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n  ,
$$
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_2 & =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t} d t \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 t^n \ln t d t \\
& =-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} 
\end{aligned}
$$
For the integral $I_1$, we differentiate the series $(*)$ once and get
$$
\frac{1}{(1-t)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n t^{n-1} 
$$
and use integration by parts, $$
I_1=2 \sum_{=1}^{\infty} n \int_0^1 t^{n-1} \ln ^2 t d t=2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^2}=-4I_2
$$
Hence
$$\boxed{\left|\frac{I_1}{I_2}  \right|=4}$$
